# Do the positive irrationals form a group with respect to multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, irrational-numbers, binary-operations

I think it's not form a group because multiple of two irrational number is rational number
Please give your answer

Comment: $(\sqrt{2})^2$...

Comment: … or $\;\pi+(1-\pi)$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. As you have stated yourself it is possible for the multiplication of two positive irrational numbers to be rational. And there are some examples above my comment. So what is your question exactly? Also don't mind the triple dots in the first comment, most people around here are much more friendly.

Answer (score 2):

It is not even a grupoid, since the multiplication of two irrational numbers is *sometimes* a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

Irrational numbers form a [semigroupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroupoid) under multiplication; the only axiom this imposes is that $(xy)z=x(yz)$ if all the products in that equation exist within the algebra of interest. Well, OK, it's something a bit more specific than that: it's a commutative semigroupoid (when the products exist), with one other nice property we'll get to in a moment. We don't have totality, because $\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\in\Bbb Q$; we don't have an identity, because $1\in\Bbb Q$; and without an identity we can't have invertibility in the sense $xx^{-1}=1$, although we do have the weaker $xyx^{-1}=y$, again if all products exist.